# How to test redirection In Flask with Python unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I am currently trying to write some unit tests for my Flask application. In many of my view functions (such as my login), I redirect to a new page. So for example:

```
@user.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    ....
    return redirect(url_for('splash.dashboard'))
```

I'm trying to verify that this redirect happens in my unit tests.  Right now, I have:

```
def test_register(self):
    rv = self.create_user('John','Smith','John.Smith@myschool.edu', 'helloworld')
    self.assertEquals(rv.status, "200 OK")
    # self.assert_redirects(rv, url_for('splash.dashboard'))
```

This function does make sure that the returned response is 200, but the last line is obviously not valid syntax.  How can I assert this?  My `create_user` function is simply:

```
def create_user(self, firstname, lastname, email, password):
        return self.app.post('/user/register', data=dict(
            firstname=firstname,
            lastname=lastname,
            email=email,
            password=password
        ), follow_redirects=True)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [Flask-Testing](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/)

there is api for [assertRedirects](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/#module-flask.ext.testing) you can use this

```
assertRedirects(response, location)

Checks if response is an HTTP redirect to the given location.
Parameters: 

    response – Flask response
    location – relative URL (i.e. without http://localhost)
```

TEST script:

```
def test_register(self):
    rv = self.create_user('John','Smith','John.Smith@myschool.edu', 'helloworld')
    assertRedirects(rv, url of splash.dashboard)
```

Answer (score 34):

Flask has [built-in testing hooks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/) and a test client, which works great for functional stuff like this.

```
from flask import url_for, request
import yourapp

test_client = yourapp.app.test_client()
with test_client:
    response = test_client.get(url_for('whatever.url'), follow_redirects=True)
    # check that the path changed
    assert request.path == url_for('redirected.url')
```

For older versions of Flask/Werkzeug the request may be available on the response:

```
from flask import url_for
import yourapp

test_client = yourapp.app.test_client()
response = test_client.get(url_for('whatever.url'), follow_redirects=True)

# check that the path changed
assert response.request.path == url_for('redirected.url')
```

The docs have more information on how to do this, although FYI if you see "flaskr", that's the name of the test class and not anything in Flask, which confused me the first time I saw it.

Comment: I strongly encourage people to use this solution, which removes Flask-Testing dependency (in general, I think using as few extensions as possible is a good thing, or only the "stable" and "big" ones, as Flask-Principal, Flask-Security, etc.). However, this solution raises a `RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available`, because `url_for` needs application context. All you have to do is putting it inside a `with app.app_context():`

Comment: "response.request" --> AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: not sure what ```response.request``` is, but if you keep the request context by using ```with app.test_client() as c:```, then you can just import request and url_for and do ```request.path == url_for(...```

Comment: From my tests, I don't think that using `request.path` would work because the path is set to the initial URL and not to the URL after the redirect. @DyRuss

Comment: From my tests I can confirm using client as a context (`with client`) does change the `request` context when `client.get` is called (and follow_redirects=True). Thanks @DyRuss

Comment: The answer to the following question solved this for me... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111814/flask-application-was-not-able-to-create-a-url-adapter-for-request

Answer (score 11):

One way is to not follow the redirects (either remove `follow_redirects` from your request, or explicitly set it to `False`).

Then, you can simply replace `self.assertEquals(rv.status, "200 OK")` with:

```
self.assertEqual(rv.status_code, 302)
self.assertEqual(rv.location, url_for('splash.dashboard', _external=True))
```

If you want to continue using `follow_redirects` for some reason, another (slightly brittle) way is to check for some expected dashboard string, like an HTML element ID in the response of `rv.data`. e.g. `self.assertIn('dashboard-id', rv.data)`

Answer (score -1):

You can verify the final path after redirects by using Flask [test client](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.test_client) as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) (using the `with` keyword). It allows keeping the final request context around in order to import the [request object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.request)  containing request path.

```py
from flask import request, url_for

def test_register(self):
    with self.app.test_client() as client:
        user_data = dict(
            firstname='John',
            lastname='Smith',
            email='John.Smith@myschool.edu',
            password='helloworld'
        )
        res = client.post('/user/register', data=user_data, follow_redirects=True)
        assert res.status == '200 OK'
        assert request.path == url_for('splash.dashboard')
```