# Flask Application was not able to create a URL adapter for request

Tags: python, flask

I have this code which used to work:

```py
import unittest

from flask import url_for

from dm.web import create_app, db


class TestApi(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """Create and configure a new app instance for each test."""
        self.app = create_app('test')
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()
        self.client = self.app.test_client(use_cookies=True)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_url(self):
        self.assertEqual('/', url_for('root.home'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But since today I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: test_url (__main__.TestApi)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joan/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 17, in test_url
    self.assertEqual('/', url_for('root.home'))
  File "/home/joan/venvs/dimensigon3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 333, in url_for
    "Application was not able to create a URL adapter for request"
RuntimeError: Application was not able to create a URL adapter for request independent URL generation. You might be able to fix this by setting the SERVER_NAME config variable.
```

From what I see in the url_for, I am getting None on the appctx.url_adapter which I don't know when it is set.

Thanks!

Comment: Tried with an easy example, but same error:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask.url\_for() error: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766082/flask-url-for-error-attempted-to-generate-a-url-without-the-application-conte)

Comment: Yes I could run it with variable SERVER_NAME set. As it says in the comment mentioned by @Ramon Medeiros. Problem solved but I was wondering why it needs server_name or a request context to give an internal url which is a direct map from function to url?

Answer (score 13):

As per this [blog post](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/flask/things-you-should-know-about-flask-server-name/), you could try this pattern, which gives you both an app context *and* a temporary request context:

```py
    def test_url(self):
        with app.app_context(), app.test_request_context():
            self.assertEqual('/', url_for('root.home'))
```

Comment: This is so good. Thank you, always wondered.